# How to filter a dataframe with dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe and a dictionary like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"letters": ["a","b","c","b","c"], "numbers": [1,2,3,1,2]})
correct_mapping={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
```

I want to filter the rows which do not have the correct mapping.

I tried this, but it breaks:

```
df[correct_mapping[df["letters"]] != df["numbers"]]
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Expected output:

```
  letters  numbers
3       b        1
4       c        2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare with `map`:

```
df[df['letters'].map(correct_mapping) != df['numbers']]                                                                                   
  letters  numbers
3       b        1
4       c        2
```